# 行列の各行をforループで計算する方法

Tags: python, python3, numpy

長さ`3575`のベクトルが`201`本ありそれを`numpy.ndarray`形式で保存しています．説明の簡単のため`x`とします．
この`x`の各行，つまり形が`(1, 3575)`のベクトルに対して計算を行いたいのですが，各行ごとを取得する方法がわかりません．どなたかわかる方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授よろしくお願いします．
以下にサイズを下げたminimal exampleを示します．

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[22, 44, 66], [90, 80, 70], [1, 3, 2]])
for _ in range(x.shape[0]):
    各行のベクトル = 各行のベクトル / np.linalg.norm(各行のベクトル)
    print(各行のベクトル)
```

Comment: 最終的な結果が得られれば良いのであれば `x / np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1)[:,None]` とする事もできます(行単位で norm を計算)。

Comment: @metropolis 最終的なとはどういう意味でしょうか？　各行がそれぞれ独立したベクトルなので，それに対応したノルムを計算したいです．

Comment: `np.linalg.norm(x, axis=1)` が「それに対応したノルム」になります。

Answer (score 1):

各行ごと取り出すのなら以下のようにできます

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[22, 44, 66], [90, 80, 70], [1, 3, 2]])
for vec in x:
    v = vec / np.linalg.norm(vec)
    print(v)
```

全体を一度に行う方法はコメントに紹介されています

Answer (score 0):

各行をごと取り出すなら

```
import numpy as np
k
x = np.array([[22, 44, 66], [90, 80, 70], [1, 3, 2]])
for i in x:
    norm = vec / np.linalg.norm(vec)
    print(norm)
```

で計算することが可能です。

また特定の行だけを指定したいのならば

```
#空のnp.arrayのリストを作成
list_x = np.array([])
for i in x:
    list_x = np.append(list_x,i)
print(list_x)
```

とやると、xに入っていたリストがリストごとに分解されてlist_xに挿入されるので、計算したいリストだけを取り出して計算することが可能です。